# Area of parallelogram in spacetime calculation and its dependence on reference frame

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

I encountered the following equation in "Gravitation and Cosmology" by S. Weinberg in the section of Riemann Curvature Tensor.

$\oint x^\rho dx^\nu=\delta a^\rho\delta b^\nu-\delta a^\nu \delta b^\rho$

This integral is evaluated along a small parallelogram with edges $\delta a^\mu$ and $\delta b^\mu$. I searched on physics stack exchange in case this question has been asked before and read in this link. [Indices of the Riemann tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346538/indices-of-the-riemann-tensor). This link says that above mentioned integrated term gives the area of the parallelogram.

My questions:

1. How is the integral giving area of the parallelogram and how is it evaluated?
2. From this a thought came into my mind. I read in Special Relativity that length of a rod is frame dependent as usually explained under Length Contraction. Is there a similar concept for area of a parallelogram? More generally, does the area of a closed curve or volume of closed surface depends on frame of reference, in both inertial and non-inertial frames?
3. If there is such a concept of dependence of area and volume on reference frame why is it never given in books (as far as I know) and expanded to n dimensions?

Comment: To be clear, the length of a rod is not frame dependent.  As a property of the rod the only way to makes sense to measure it is in the rest frame of the rod.  So we call that measurement "proper length".  What you are referring to is the result of someone in a moving frame of reference relative to the rod trying to get a measurement of the rod's length as they pass by using light pulses or other remote methods to bounce signals off the ends.  But yes, in a moving frame the appearance of other geometries will change.  I see it as HW in some modern physics books.

Comment: By length of the rod, I meant as in a moving frame of reference.

Comment: Okay, my comment still applies.  2-dim and 3-dim objects will appear to contract along the direction of relative motion.  I am not sure what formula you expect to find, but I see the examples in modern physics books.  In fact in the early days of hadron model there was a phenomenon called the Licht-Pangamenta Parton contraction, i.e. the observed volume of a parton moving near the speed on light as seen in the collider/accelerator frame.

Comment: Thanks for the example. It was just a thought in mind and don't seek any formula. To be honest, I haven't studied High Energy Physics so probably that's the reason I never encountered any such example. Now my main concern is that integral only. It has blown my mind.

Comment: Well the "formula" would be the same as it always is just modified appropriately.  Say a rectangle is still l*w, but with the appropriate dimension contracted.  A circle perhaps becomes an ellipse, etc.  A more interesting question is whether the effect could cause some sort of contradictory result, like preventing the edges from closing.  I would venture to guess that this is addressed in some text on GR or DG, GT etc.

Comment: Could you give the link to the section where it is given?

Comment: https://ftp.space.dtu.dk/pub/Henrik/Weinberg%20S.%20Gravitation%20and%20cosmology..%20principles%20and%20applications%20of%20the%20general%20theory%20of%20relativity%20%28Wiley,%201972%29%28ISBN%200471925675%29%28685s%29.pdf On page number 136

Answer (score 2):

In an m-dimensional spacetime (i.e., with m-1 spatial dimensions), the simplest and most basic fact to understand is that m-dimensional volume is invariant under Lorentz boosts. This is easiest to visualize for m=2, i.e., 1+1 dimensions. In the t-x plane, a boost transforms a square into a parallelogram with the same area. The fact that it preserves area basically follows from symmetry. E.g., if a boost in the +x direction reduced the area, then a similar boost in the -x direction would have to put the area back to its original value. But this would mean that +x boosts reduced area and -x boosts increased it, which violates the symmetry of space under parity (or rotation).

For m=2, the expression you give in your question measures the same thing as the cross product. However, when we represent a cross product as a 3-vector in 3-space, we're taking advantage of a special property of 3-dimensional space. In general that doesn't work, and this kind of area is a rank-2 tensor. We could use rank-2 tensors in freshman physics rather than the cross product, but I guess that would be too hard and scary for 18-year-olds.

Another pretty simple fact to understand is that a k-volume for $k<m$ is not going to have all the nice properties we would expect from Euclidean intuition. For example, we would like the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by k linearly independent vectors to be nonzero, but this fails for k=1 if we use the metric to measure things, because we have null vectors.

For $k=m-1$, there is a nice representation of the k-volume as a covector. E.g., 3-volume in 3+1 dimensions can be treated as a covector. Then the inner product of that covector with a vector gives the m-volume that they span together. The 3-volume is spacelike if the covector is timelike, etc.

> If there is such a concept of dependence of area and volume on reference frame why is it never given in books (as far as I know) and expanded to n dimensions?

Most relativity books will discuss this wherever they discuss the Levi-Civita tensor.